# Change unselectedItemTintColor for single tab bar icon

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a subclass of `UITabBarController` with 5 items.

The 5th item is the user avatar.

```
final class HomeSceneViewController: UITabBarController {

  init(tabs: [UIViewController]) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    viewControllers = tabs

    configureUI()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
  }
}

private extension HomeSceneViewController {
  func configureUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .red
    tabBar.tintColor = .blue
  }
}
```

Currently each view controller sets it's own `tabBarItem` property using `tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: tab.iconOff, selectedImage: tab.iconOn)` which works, however the `unselectedItemTintColor` is setting an overlay on the avatar which I do not want as it should show the avatar as is.

Is it possible to set `unselectedItemTintColor` on a per tab basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing the image with renderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) like this:

```swift
tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil,
                          image: tab.iconOff?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
                          selectedImage: tab.iconOn?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
```